# Angular 6 checkbox value lost on pressing back button

Tags: angular, angular6

Angular 6 checkbox value lost on pressing back button. I used routing for all forms. All other input type working fine except checkbox. When I pressed back button radio keeps value but all checkbox value got unchecked.

.html
`

```
<form #ingredientForm="ngForm" class="editForm" novalidate>
    <div class="card space-wrap">
      <div class="card--content" *ngFor = "let data of options">
        <input type="checkbox" #ingredient[data.name]="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="ingredientType[data.name]" value="{{data.name}}" name="select" id="{{data.name}}"/>
        <label for="{{data.name}}">{{data.name}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" [disabled]=disable (click)="goToNext(ingredientForm)" class="btn btn-mobile btn-primary btn-fixed">Next: Ingredients</button>
  </form>
```

`This is my form model ingredient is used for checbox`

```
export class FormData {
    finger: string = '';
    chocolate: string = '';
    ingredient: any = {};
    message: string = '';
    packaging: string = '';
    clear() {
        this.finger = '';
        this.chocolate = '';
        this.ingredient = '';
        this.message = '';
        this.packaging = '';
    }
}
```

`

Comment: maybe data.name is inconsistent ?

Comment: data.name is just simple text.
options = [
   {name:"test", checked:false}, 
   {name:"test1",checked:false}, 
   {name:"test2",checked:false},
   {name:"test4",checked:false}
   ];

Comment: But you are using is as array/object key so this might be it

Comment: @Antoniossss can you please explain me the right way to use this?